# Normalized Group Values in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, histogram, normalization

I want to plot normalized count grouped values with seaborn. At first, I tried doing the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = sns.histplot(
                data = df,
                x = 'age_bins', 
                hue = 'Showup',
                multiple="dodge", 
                stat = 'count',
                shrink = 0.4,
                )
```

[Original Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyBPp.png)

Now I want to normalize each bar relative to the overall 'bin' count. The only way I successeded to do so was by doing this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = sns.histplot(
                data = df,
                x = 'age_bins', 
                hue = 'Showup',
                multiple="fill", 
                stat = 'count',
                shrink = 0.4,
                )
```

[multiple = 'fill'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5LUI.png)

Now this made me achieve what I wanted in terms of values, but is there anyway to plot the same results but with bars dodged beside each other instead of above each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by ages and "showup", count them, then change "showup" to individual columns. Then divide each row by the row total and create a bar plot via pandas:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ages = ['<10', '<20', '<30', '<40', '<50', '<60', '<70', '++70']
df = pd.DataFrame({'age_bins': np.random.choice(ages, 10000),
                   'Showup': np.random.choice([True, False], 10000, p=[0.88, 0.12])})
df_counts = df.groupby(['age_bins', 'Showup']).size().unstack().reindex(ages)
df_percentages = df_counts.div(df_counts.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100

sns.set() # set default seaborn style
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
df_percentages.plot.bar(rot=0, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage per age group')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: groupby, calculate percentages and show bar plot]